# What is the difference between cyber security ontologies and scenario ontologies in this system?

Tags: terminology, knowledge-representation, ontologies

I have been reading the paper [Towards a Cognitive System for Decision Support in Cyber Operations](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1097/STIDS2013_T13_OltramariEtAl.pdf). And I have been trying to understand the role of two ontologies proposed here, **cyber security ontologies** and **scenario ontologies**.

I have asked a question on CGS SE, [What are the practical uses of ontologies?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9156/what-are-the-practical-uses-of-ontologies) and the role of the **ACT-R** architecture in this system have become clear to some extent, but the question about the ontologies is that:

Does the cyber security ontologies make the ideas in the TENA's Repo understandable for ACT-R or the ideas that are in the repo has to be represented by an ontology called **cyber security ontologies** in order to be understandable for the **ACT-R** architecture?

**The Cognitive System realized in the TENA framework:**

[image: The Cognitive System realized in the TENA framework]

Questions raising from this Figure can be:

1. What is the difference between the **cyber security ontologies** and the **scenario ontologies**?
2. What kind of knowledge the **scenario ontologies** represent?
3. And of course what is the reason that the scenario ontologies are connected to **Event data management** module instead of TENA's Repo?

**ACT-R Architecture:**

[image: ACT-R Architecture]

**TENA Architecture:**

[image: TENA Architecture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more detail can be found p97. Here "ontologies" are basically encodings of database contents (which represent cyber attacks, incidents, and malicious/ impacted software programs) parseable by external sources, e.g. ACT-R. The event data management system keeps track of (real) attacks/ incidents, or possibly simulated ones. TENA is a Testing and Training Enabling Architecture. In a sense the Cyber Security Ontologies are all the "Nouns", and the Scenario Ontologies are "Verbs" that operate on the Nouns. ACT-R takes these inputs and attempts to create a conceptual linking or model. In a sense the ACT-R is a machine learning system for cyber-attack-related events and entities. It is a framework for outputting a (maybe statistical) analysis that could be used to predict future attacks from the structure of past ones.

> The need for controlled vocabularies, taxonomies, and
>   ontologies to make progress toward a science of cyber security
>   is recognized in [26] and [27] as well. In the domain of cyber
>   security, the ontologies would include, among other things,
>   the classification of cyber attacks, cyber incidents, and
>   malicious and impacted software programs. From our point of
>   view, which seeks to accurately represent the human-side of
>   cyber security, we also expand our analysis to: (i) the different
>   roles that system users, defenders and policy makers play in
>   the context of cyber security; (ii) the different jobs and
>   functions that the members of cyber defender team play and
>   the knowledge, skills and abilities needed to fulfill these
>   functions. In order to reduce the level of effort, we will reuse
>   existing ontologies when possible<sup>6</sup> and only create new
>   ontologies that support the use cases we select.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which reference are you mentioning by saying "some more detail can be found p97"?

Comment: @AliNfr The paper you linked in your question (Towards a Cognitive System for Decision Support in Cyber Operations) starts on pg. 94 of the STIDS Conference Proceedings. I assume he is referring to the 4th page of that document (which is labeled pg. 97).

Comment: @vzn what is your opinion about the question I asked, "Does the cyber security ontologies make the ideas in the TENA's Repo understandable for ACT-R or the ideas that are in the repo has to be represented by an ontology called cyber security ontologies in order to be understandable for the ACT-R architecture?" I have the same question about the scenario ontologies and the event data management system, Are the TENA repo and event data management system providing the instances needed for the ontologies of this system?

Comment: the ontology is a sort of "packaging" for data. the TENA repository/ event data system are not built to interface with ACT-R directly. they have different purposes. the ontologies are a packaging of the data that makes the data consumable by ACT-R. some of this is an abstraction that involves assumptions packaging the data in this way is feasible.

Comment: What is the main reason that we need ontology in this system? ,The paper mentions two reasons :" (ii) the flexible behavior required
by coupling alternative strategies of response to specific cyber
threats, updating and revising strategies when the
circumstances of the attack or the environmental conditions
evolve;(iv) interacting in a team by building a mental
representation of the co-workers as well as of the enemies."

Comment: I think that the whole idea of using ontologies is because of interaction with the human agents because if there was no human we could do the same actions(cyber defence or attack, and switching between strategies according to circumstances) without ontologies.

Comment: cyber attacks and defense are [currently] entirely a human directed process. not sure what you are asserting; your scenario starting with "if there was no human..." makes no sense because its [counterfactual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional). suggest further discussion go in [chat] instead

Comment: By saying "if there was no human" I mean that if we design an advanced firewall that has flexible behavior and can use different technics in different circumstances (e.g. different pattern checking technics), and this firewall acts as a cyber attack defender we can say we don't have any human at least in our cyber defence.

Comment: ok yes that is the general purpose of the overall design as indicated in other sections of the paper. to develop a general machine learning/ intelligence for cyber attacks/ defense that augments human judgement by integrating diverse systems (eg ACT-R/ TENA/ combination may not be proposed/ used in this way anywhere else). however overall this is subject to the very difficult problem of false positives/ false negatives, eg similar to spam filters, etc; their proposal is speculative in some ways & involves major unproven assumptions.